# Laravel Nova - Map database json column to field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-nova

I have a database model with `json` column type called `attributes`. This column will contain additional details of the model.

For example:
`attributes : {'desc' : 'test', 'width' : '500'}`.

I would like to display individual attribute (`desc` & `width`) in `attributes` column as a html field in Laravel admin resource.

I checked supported [field types](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/fields.html#field-types) and doesn't seem supports.

Any suggestions how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the recommended answer but i've found a way that should work for you.

Use an Eloquent Mutator: [Eloquent Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators)

Then you define a `getDescAttribute` and a `setDescAttribute` and pass it in nova like a property on the model like so:

```
Text::make('Desc', 'desc')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well the problem comes when the "desc" and "width" are dynamic attributes and you don't know the whole list of those attributes. Any ideas ?

Comment: @ArmeniaH you could get the array from ->fields, iterate over the keys, and add fields as needed in the edit context. This would be a mess in the index view as each row could have different keys in the array.

Answer (score 11):

Here's how I was able to accomplish this in Nova 2.0. In my case I have a JSON column called *fields*. In the model, *fields* is cast to an array.

```
protected $casts = [
    'fields' => 'array'
];
```

Then in the resource, the column is mapped using the -> operator.

```
Text::make('Name', 'fields->name')
```

Answer (score 0):

For example the value for 'desc' column is something like :

```
"{attributes : {'desc' : 'test', 'width' : '500'}}"
```

You can directly put it in table format :

```
KeyValue::make('Desc', 'desc**.attributes**')
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There is a package that allows you to achieve what you want to without any unnecessary changes to the behaviour of your model.

https://github.com/64robots/nova-fields

This would allow you to define each key of JSON array as actual fields that can be modified.