# Laravel Nova ignore a field if empty using ->fillUsing()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova

I have 3 fields "name", "email" and "url". These 3 fields are casted to a json in 1 column in my database.

Now if you fill in just the url I want to save only `{url: "value"}` in the database. If you fill in email and name I want to save only `{name: "john", email: "john@gmail.com"}` in the database.

This is how I try do to it:

```
Text::make('To Name', 'toName')
            ->sortable()
            ->fillUsing(
                function ($request, $model) {
                    return $request->toName;
                }
            ),

Text::make('To Email', 'toEmail')
            ->sortable()
            ->fillUsing(
                function ($request, $model) {
                    return $request->toEmail;
                }
            ),

Text::make('To Url', 'toUrl')
            ->sortable()
            ->fillUsing(
                function ($request, $model) {
                    return $request->toUrl;
                }
            ),
```

But I keep getting this error:

> General error: 1364 Field 'to' doesn't have a default value

Am I returning something wrong?

Comment: Check whether following answer is useful, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57418317/4273867

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, use Laravel mutator and some changes in your fillUsing. Note toName, toEmail, toUrl are virtual attributes, and to_json contain json values of these columns in model!

```
// database\migrations\2019_08_28_045853_create_infos_table.php
...
        Schema::create('infos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('label',100);
            $table->json('to_json');
        });

// app\Nova\Info.php
...    
public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            Text::make('Label'),
            Text::make('To Name', 'toName')
                ->sortable()
                ->fillUsing(
                    function ($request, $model) {
                        if(!empty($request->toName)){
                            if(!empty($model['to_json'])){
                                $json = json_decode($model['to_json'],true);
                            }else{
                                $json = [];
                            }
                            $json['name'] = $request->toName;
                            $model['to_json'] = json_encode($json);
                        }
                    }
                ),
            Text::make('To Email', 'toEmail')
                ->sortable()
                ->fillUsing(
                    function ($request, $model) {
                        if(!empty($request->toEmail)){
                            if(!empty($model['to_json'])){
                                $json = json_decode($model['to_json'],true);
                            }else{
                                $json = [];
                            }
                            $json['email'] = $request->toEmail;
                            $model['to_json'] = json_encode($json);
                        }
                    }
                ),
            Text::make('To Url', 'toUrl')
                ->sortable()
                ->fillUsing(
                    function ($request, $model) {
                        if(!empty($request->toUrl)){
                            if(!empty($model['to_json'])){
                                $json = json_decode($model['to_json'],true);
                            }else{
                                $json = [];
                            }
                            $json['url'] = $request->toUrl;
                            $model['to_json'] = json_encode($json);
                        }
                    }
                ),
        ];
    }

// app\Info.php
...
class Info extends Model
{
    public function gettoNameAttribute(){
        if(empty($this->attributes['to_json'])){
            return "";
        }
        $json = $this->attributes['to_json'];
        $result = json_decode($json,true);
        if(!empty($result['name'])){
            return $result['name'];
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }

    public function gettoEmailAttribute(){
        if(empty($this->attributes['to_json'])){
            return "";
        }
        $json = $this->attributes['to_json'];
        $result = json_decode($json,true);
        if(!empty($result['email'])){
            return $result['email'];
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }

    public function gettoUrlAttribute(){
        if(empty($this->attributes['to_json'])){
            return "";
        }
        $json = $this->attributes['to_json'];
        $result = json_decode($json,true);
        if(!empty($result['url'])){
            return $result['url'];
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```